# AS3 playback of sound byte array doesn't begin at the start

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, arrays

I'm currently recording and storing a ByteArray of sound and then playing it back. But for some reason the playback starting position of the ByteArray is 163840, not 0 as I need it to be.

Would anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks,

Mark

```
var soundBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var sound:Sound = new Sound();
var ch:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var recordingsArray:Array = new Array();
```

//imagine I have successfully recorded and stored the sound into recordingsArray

```
soundBA.clear();
soundBA.length = 0;

//I collect the recorded byteArray within an array
soundBA.writeBytes(recordingsArray[0]);

soundBA.position = 0;
trace("Start POS "+soundBA.position); //traces 0

sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, sound_sampleDataHandler, false, 0, true);
ch=sound.play();
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateSeek, false, 0, true);



public function updateSeek(event:Event):void {

    trace("current Pos "+soundBA.position); //the first trace event is "current Pos 163840"
}



function sound_sampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void {

    for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++)
    {
        if (soundBA.bytesAvailable < 4)
        {
            break;
        }
        var sample:Number = soundBA.readFloat();
        event.data.writeFloat(sample);
        event.data.writeFloat(sample);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `soundBA.position` is position in byte array, not position of playback. It runs ahead of playback position because of sound lag. To determine current playback position use `SoundChannel.position`:

```
public function updateSeek(event:Event):void {
    trace("current pos in ms: " + ch.position);
    trace("current pos in bytes: " + (ch.position * 44.1 * 4 * 2));
    trace("current pos in %: " + (100 * ch.position / sound.length));
}
```

**UPD**: I was referring to the case when sound is decoded using additional `Sound` object, e.g.:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class SoundTest extends Sprite
    {
        private var soundSrc:Sound;
        private var soundPlayer:Sound;
        private var soundData:ByteArray;
        private var soundChannel:SoundChannel;

        public function SoundTest()
        {
            soundSrc = new Sound();
            soundSrc.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startPlayback);
            soundSrc.load(new URLRequest("sound.mp3"));
        }

        private function startPlayback(e:Event = null):void
        {
            soundData = new ByteArray();
            soundSrc.extract(soundData, soundSrc.length * 44.1, 0);
            soundData.position = 0;

            soundPlayer = new Sound();
            soundPlayer.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData);
            soundChannel = soundPlayer.play();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateTime);
        }

        private function onSampleData(e:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++)
            {
                if (soundData.bytesAvailable < 4)
                {
                    break;
                }
                var sampleL:Number = soundData.readFloat();
                var sampleR:Number = soundData.readFloat();
                e.data.writeFloat(sampleL);
                e.data.writeFloat(sampleR);

            }
        }

        private function updateTime(e:Event):void
        {
            trace("current pos in ms: " + soundChannel.position);
            trace("current pos in bytes: " + (soundChannel.position * 44.1 * 4 * 2));
            trace("current pos in % (method 1): " + (100 * soundChannel.position / soundSrc.length));
            // it also works
            trace("current pos in % (method 2): " + (100 * soundChannel.position / (soundData.length / (44.1 * 4 * 2))));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for replying. Just one small issue though. 

trace("current pos in %: " + (100 * ch.position / sound.length));

THis only seems to run until approx 0.56. i.e. if I let the recording play fully despite it's length the end % value is always around 0.56.

current pos in %: 0.5668934240362812

Would you have any idea why this might be?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I've misread your question. How do you prepare the byte array with sound data? I was referring to the case when you obtain `ByteArray` by usng `Sound.extract()` method. It is common technique: firstly you load and decode mp3 file using `Sound` object (`srcSound.load(...)`), then you extract bytes (`srcSound.extract(soundBA, ...)`), and finally you play extracted bytes with another (dynamic) sound (`dstSound.play()`). In that case you can obtain position as `100 * dstChannel.position / srcSound.length`.

Comment: If you have `ByteArray` with already decoded sound, I assume that you can use `decodedBA.length / (44.1 * 4 * 2)` to obtain sound length in ms (instead of sound.length).

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Semen.

For anyones future ref the % line is:(sound is the decoded bytearray)

trace("current pos in %: " + (100 * ch.position / (sound.length / (44.1 * 4))));

Comment: Within your example code could you tell me how I would go about starting the playback of the soundData byteArray half way through the total sound time? e.g. say the recording was 10 seconds long and I want to start playback 5 seconds in. Thanks, Mark

Comment: If you are using `Sound` to decompress data, notice third parameter of `extract()` method (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html). It allows you to specify the sample at which extraction begins (but don't forget to correct `length` parameter accordingly). And in the case of byte array with pre-decoded sound you can simply change it's position: `soundBA.position = startMs * 44.1 * 4; var sample:Number = soundBA.readFloat(); //etc.` (assuming that sound is mono).

Comment: By the way, extracting the whole sound data from `Sound` object is not very good approach as it leads to large memory consuming. It will be much better to extract small pieces of data during each `SampleDataEvent`. You can even extract the data directly into `event.data` byte array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5832/discussion-between-crooksy88-and-semen)